# Retreiving numbers into an array - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to retrieve all numbers of my customers but i only get the number of the first customer. Why is this happening even tho i am looping the object?

**Controller**

```
$customers = Customer::where('user_id',1)->get();

       $phone = [];
        foreach($customers as $phone => $keys)
        {
            $phoneArray= $keys;

            return $phone;

        }
```

i actually want my phoneArray to have numbers like phoneArray = "44123,13131,1232323,131231"

Comment: You have to return after the loop.

Comment: You have already asked this question under a different account of which has a sufficient answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204698/returning-all-details-from-database/47206040#47206040

Comment: What you talking about? and Click where?

Comment: The link I gave the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redeclaring the `$phone` variable in your loop. Also, you do not need to return in your `foreach` otherwise it won't loop through all the elements.

Change it to:

```
$phoneArray = [];

foreach($customers as $key => $client){
    $phoneArray[] = $client->phone;
}

return implode(',', $phoneArray);
```

Comment: I want to get the numbers in this way  'phoneArray = "050,114, 156"'

Comment: @XamarinDevil What are the values of `$keys` and `$phone`?

Comment: i think they are the same

Comment: Then the `$phoneArray` should be exactly like you want it though. It should be an array of the numbers. You want it as a string?

Comment: i want it as a string. currently it is not in a string. i need to pick out the numbers in string like in the comment above (1st)

Comment: Okay this is returning client's all details .. i want just phone number but when i map `return implode(',', $phoneArray->phone);`  i get an error `"Trying to get property of non-object"
`